# Differentiating D3 brane worldvolume theories with NS5 brane and NS5 antibrane boundary conditions

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, boundary-conditions, yang-mills, branes

In ['Supersymmetric Boundary Conditions in N=4 Super Yang-Mills Theory'](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.2902), Gaiotto and Witten derive boundary conditions for the worldvolume theory of the D3 brane. In particular the boundary conditions (see pages 8-10) on the fermionic field $\Psi$ is 
$
\Gamma_3\Psi=\Psi' \otimes \vartheta
$
where $\Psi'$ transforms under the boundary Lorentz and R-symmetry, while 
$$\vartheta=
\begin{pmatrix} a \\ 1\end{pmatrix},$$
up to scaling.

It is stated later on below equation (4.32) that the choices $a=\infty$ and $a=0$ correspond to NS5-brane and NS5-antibrane boundary conditions.

My question is, how does one discern which value of $a$ corresponds to NS5-brane or NS5-antibrane? Can this even be determined, or is the notion of brane and antibrane only defined relative to each other in this case?